# android : How to erase rectagle on view

Tags: android

I make ImageView and create rectagle like this

img is ImageView

Rect a= new Rect(tx,ty,bx,by); 
canvas.drawRect(a,paint);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

like this code
 when i touch button i create 5 different rectangle on my ImageView and put it in ArrayList for saving rectangle info.
and i create touchlistener and detect that rectangle is touched

in my code there is no onDraw method

here is question how can i erase specific  touched rectangle

Comment: Understand you it's impossible, try to edit your question and post more details....What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to erase touched rectangle only not entire rectangle

Comment: my solution is that canvas.darwColor(Color.white); img.invalidate();
and then redraw rest of contents